# Woocommerce product-category-description on productpage

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a question regarding woocommerce and the product-pages. I want to output the text and pictures stored in the product category.

For example, if the product is connected to the categories "electro" and "car", I want to output the text and pictures stored in the woocommerce-category description of "electro" and "cars".

I used the following code, to get at least some information displayed, thats stored in the `functions.php` (like some text in the `listitem`)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page($category) {
    global $post;
    echo '<ul class="myCat"> ';

if ( has_term( 'Cocktails', 'product_cat' ) ) {
echo'
Wird gerne genutz in Rezepten f&uuml;r:<br />
<li class="icon-glass2">1</li>
';}
elseif ( has_term( 'Dressings', 'product_cat' ) ) {
echo'
<li>2</li>
';}
if ( has_term( 'Limonaden', 'product_cat' ) ) {
echo'
<li class="icon-glass2">3</li>
';}
elseif ( has_term( 'Kochen', 'product_cat' ) ) {
echo'
<li class="icon-glass2">4</li>
';} 
elseif ( has_term( 'Backen', 'product_cat' ) ) {
echo'
<i class="icon-glass2">5</i>
';} 
elseif (has_term ('shrub', 'product_cat')){echo 'shrub';}
 else {
echo 'test';
}echo '</ul><br style="clear:both;" /> ';}
```

There is however some code I found, but I dont know how to get it working with my code.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'custom_add_product_description', 12);

function custom_add_product_description ($category) {
$cat_id        =    $category->term_id;
$prod_term    =    get_term($cat_id,'product_cat');
$description=    $prod_term->description;

echo '<div>'.$description.'</div>';
}
```

I would be happy, if someone could help me putting those together.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

global $post;

$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',);
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat', $args);
$count = count($terms); 
if ($count > 0) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<div>';
        echo $term->description;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

?>
```

To add category description to single product page, using `content-single-product.php` template file,

Comment: Wow! Worked immediately - thanks a lot Pullata Praveen!

Comment: I used a slightly different approach now: I use the functios.php and added:

`add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_extra_button_on_product_page', 30 );

function my_extra_button_on_product_page($category) {
 global $post;
$args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',);
$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat', $args);
$count = count($terms); 
  echo '. ';
if ($count > 0) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo '<div>';
        echo $term->description;
        echo '</div>';
}}}`

Comment: thanks @sPanse and the code which you provided also works perfectly

Comment: Hello again @Pullata Praveen! 
Maybe you or one of the boys and girls from stackoverflow might help with a futher feature request regarding our small "category-name-code-thing". 
Do you see a way of adding the categorys URL to the output on single-product-pages? So far I tried literly everything i found on the first two google pages - but my php knowledge is so little...
Looking forward hearing from you guys! 
Best regards, 
Benedikt

Comment: after 2 hours trial and error :) 
[link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/display-woocommerce-categories-subcategories-and-products-in-separate-lists--cms-25479)

Comment: @Benedikt Sorry for the late reply after 3 years i saw your comment now.